# Insert into statement with parentheses in column names

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am use Java to insert into a MSSQL database. I have column names with parentheses in them like `Duration_(Mins)`.

I am trying to execute a statement like:

`INSERT INTO mytable (Duration_(Mins)) VALUES (?)`

and I am getting the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near '('`

So I am guessing I need some way to "escape" the bracket?

Comment: You can try using backticks around the column name - `Duration_(Mins)`

Comment: I have tried, I assume by backtick you mean "`".

Comment: Yeah I meant that only. Didn't it work?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near '`'

Comment: Try using double quotes - "Duration_(Mins)".

Comment: Try enclosing the column name in []

Comment: Like, `INSERT INTO mytable ([Duration_(Mins)]) VALUES (?)`

Comment: If at all possible, i'd fix the database (remove the parens from the column name).  this will cause you no end of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MS-SQL Server, this should work:

```
INSERT INTO mytable ([Duration_(Mins)]) VALUES (?)
```

For details, refer this link: 
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132046.aspx#DelimitedIdentifiers